# DB (oracle) column description using hibernate / data dictionary

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, database-schema, hbm2ddl

we use Hibernate for creating the DB schema and as ORM. We like to have the persistent layer exchangable between Postgres, Oracle and HSQLDB.

Since there is also a DB team for Oracle, there are many times questions like "What does this column mean?" and the answer is in the Java class as JavaDoc. So what I am looking for is a possibility to add description to columns by using the text at the class property (best would be the java doc). However, google didn't find anything helpful except of this:

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4369

I doubt, that this request will be implemented.

One idea might be to write my own annotation @ColumnDesc("my description") and write a lib, that scans class for this annotation and generate extra DDL (alter table) script for the column description and execute this script. This seems little bit complicated, since I need to get the table and column name.

So my question is:

Is there a workaround or other easy way to create column descriptions in the DB (oracle) when creating the DB with Hibernate Tools (hbm2ddl)?

Alternative: Is there an easy way to generate a data dictionary for the tables and columns generated by hibernate? (Please don't say JavaDoc, DBAs can't read JavaDocs)

We use the annotation hibernate defintion (no XML).

Thanks for any hint!

Regards,

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

A custom annotation sounds like the right approach to me.

You could then scan for the custom annotation and the Hibernate/JPA annotations, and output DDL that alters the tables to create the column descriptions.

You may have to either reverse-engineer how hibernate forms the table and column names, or possibly figure out how to re-use the relevant classes from hibernate to produce them.